# My keyboard does not work anymore

Tags: windows-xp, installation, boot, keyboard

My keyboard stopped working some time ago.There was no error shown.When i open keyboard option in control panel then there are no drivers shown there like standard 102/102..etc.
Similarly there is no keyboard entry in device manager.It sometimes work on restarting the machine but stops working after some minutes.Then when it was working on startup i installed new windows OS but the problem is still there.

NOTE:When i unplug and plug the keyboard back then the three lights blinks.It surely means there is no problem with hardware.
  What should i do?can anybody help me?

NOTE: Sorry ,i forgot it is an PS/2 keyboard

Comment: Plug the keyboard into another USB port. Does it work them? Plug it into another computer. Does it work there? If not, it's broken.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot unplug a PS/2 keyboard and plug it in again and expect it to work without rebooting, unfortunately.  The BIOS has to initialize it at boot-up time.

The fact that the lights blink means that the keyboard is getting power and is initializing.  It doesn't necessarily mean that there is no hardware fault.

Try the keyboard in another computer, and try another keyboard in your computer.

You will probably find that your keyboard won't work in any computer, and someone else's keyboard will work perfectly in yours.  Keyboards die - it's a fact of life.

Luckily they're pretty cheap, but do yourself a favor and don't buy the absolute cheapest.  Try them out before you buy one - get a feel for the keystroke action, and choose one that feels right for you.

Comment: Also mouse is also started freezing after this keyboard problem occured.My mouse now freezez in one or two days then i have to reboot my computer.

Comment: You can rule out software by booting up off an Ubuntu CD and selecting "Try Ubuntu" to run a live OS off the CD.  If the keyboard and mouse behave OK then it's your windows installation, but that's unlikely as you have already reinstalled windows.  Also, is your mouse PS/2?

Comment: yes my mouse and keyboard are ps/2

Comment: If i could not find the solution plz also tell me which keyboard to buy PS/2 or USB?

Comment: Well, if the problem is with the keyboard, then it doesn't matter.  If the problem is with the PS/2 controller on the motherboard, then get USB.  So, I'd go for USB as it's the safest bet.  They're also the most common now.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem in your registry which is caused by wrong values in the UpperFilters.

The problem could be for example that an additional keyboard driver file is defined but missing which causes the normal mouse/keyboard driver to fail.

Here you can find a detailed step by step solution that could fix your problem:

http://blog.eddsn.com/2012/08/keyboard-and-mouse-not-working-in-windows/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.